# Determining which pattern generated a webpack asset's file name

Tags: webpack

I'm working on a [webpack plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/tree/v3/packages/workbox-webpack-plugin) that processes a compilation's assets and needs to take specific actions depending on why the asset was created and named.

For instance, if an asset is a sourcemap, I'd like to skip over it.

Or if an asset has a `[hash]` or `[chunkhash]` in its name, I'd like to avoid doing my own hashing.

Unfortunately, I don't see the necessary metadata exposed in the assets' entries to determine the answer to those questions. There is not, for instance, a boolean `isSourcemap` or `isHashed` property exposed anywhere. There also isn't a property exposed that includes information about which pattern was used to generate the final asset name.

The asset's file path is exposed, though, so I'm wondering whether I could safely infer that an asset is a sourcemap by checking to see whether the basename matches the `output.sourceMapFilename` pattern. Or somehow check to see if a file's name includes a portion that might have been generated by `[hash]` or `[chunkhash]`.

Is there any approach that would allow a plugin to answer the question "does this asset's name either match or originate from this naming pattern?"

Comment: Have you found out the solution for this? I have a similar problem when I want to check if a given asset is a Webpack JavaScript chunk or something else.

Comment: I _think_ https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/9687 will help for my use case (the `immutable` property) in `webpack` v5, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Hmm, thank you! I am going to look if it helps in my case.